# How to set the version of gopls to install with vscode Go extension?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

I'm running go1.16, the latest gopls version is not compabtible with it. Confirmed it at https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/README.md. The installation fails with below error

```
Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/bin/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.12.0\ngo/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.13.1/internal/lsp/source/options.go:25:2: //go:build comment without // +build comment\n"
}

1 tools failed to install.
```

I want to use vscode to install a version that is compatible, for example v0.12.4.

I can get it to work by manually installing it, is there a way to configure the version for gopls in vscode ?

Comment: From the Gopls page you linked to: https://github.com/golang/tools/releases/tag/gopls%2Fv0.11.0. At the bottom is an archive of the source code. But it would be easier to just update your Go toolchain.

Comment: The source code there is for gopls. Technically, I could use the same suggestion for the go-extension; still it is not worth the effort. There gotta be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Currently(at least under my comprehension), if you want to rollback to specific version of any vscode extension, you can go to the extension page and click the dropdown to find `Install another version`.
[image: Extension Go in extension page]

Comment: This won't solve the issue as older extension would still install latest gopls.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no option to configure tool versions in `vscode-go`. It blindly picks the [latest version](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/b2303c5ebfcbbc6ea77e4cb08f393fb4cab4e461/tools/installtools/main.go#L172) available for gopls. A version is not set [here](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/b2303c5ebfcbbc6ea77e4cb08f393fb4cab4e461/tools/installtools/main.go#L38C4-L38C28) or [here](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/tools/allTools.ts.in#L202).

Only option is to manually install a lower version. Highest gopls version that work with go1.16 is v0.12.4, install it with below command,

```
go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.12.4
```

And disable check for updates with below setting. The extension currently check updates only for gopls.

```
"go.toolsManagement.checkForUpdates": "off"
```